# I just want to retrieve the content of wordpress. How it can be done?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api

I am trying to get the data from mySql. In mySql data is stored from wordpress. and I also want to convert in json format but wordpress functions the_content() is not working.
I am working in php

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM othpk_posts where post_type='product' AND post_status='publish'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
$data =array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($data, array('id' => $row['ID'], 'productName' => $row['the_title()'], 'productContent'=>$row['the_content() ']));
}
$json = json_encode($data);
echo $json;
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: `$row['the_title()']`, `$row['the_content() ']`...`the_title()` and `the_content()` are functions, not column names in the database. Look at the database to see what the columns are called (or do a `var_dump($row)` to see what it actually contains) and use that

Comment: WordPress has native functions for interacting with the database, specifically [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/), which I'd encourage you to look into

Answer (score 0):

You are using WordPress functions to access the database columns instead of using the column name since you are working from a separate PHP file that is not attached to WordPress

To get your query correctly your code should be like so:

```
   // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM othpk_posts where post_type='product' AND post_status='publish'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $data =array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   //We use the column name below not WordPress function
        array_push($data, array('id' => $row['ID'], 'productName' => $row['post_title'], 'productContent'=>$row['post_content']));
    }
    $json = json_encode($data);
    echo $json;
    } else {
      echo "0 results";
    }
    
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: doing so give me a blank web page

Comment: A blank page usually means you don't have error reporting turned on

Comment: Test your connections if the details are correct and turn on error reporting